# "Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Value is not a valid ByteString" error

Tags: ajax, unicode

I am sending AJAX request like:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            url: 'http://localhost:1234/api/file/upload',
            data: formData,
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false, 
            headers: {
                "FileName": filename
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {}
});
```

When `filename` is not written in English(some other languages) I'm getting this error:

> Error Scan fileTypeError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Value is not a valid ByteString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP header `field-value` is restricted, see [RFC 7230 §3.2, §3.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2).

The header is wrong, anyway. Use `Content-Disposition` ([RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266)) instead. It comes with a parameter `filename*` that allows for encoded values ([RFC 8187](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8187)). For example, the decoded file name `£ and € rates` is encoded:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename*=UTF-8''%c2%a3%20and%20%e2%82%ac%20rates
```

Comment: should I add this header to the AJAX call ?

Comment: I cannot answer that. Ask the person responsible for `http://localhost:1234/api/file/upload`.